# Do I have the legal right to let Twitter customer support delete an email exchange I had with them?

Tags: constitutional-law

I did have an exchange with them and afterwards, now, I would like them to delete it after solving the problem. Is that possible? thanks

Comment: To be clear, you're asking if the constitution allows you to grant permission for Twitter to delete emails that they have from you? That would depends on what country you're in.

Comment: yes. Twitter is in the US, so is it relevant where i am?

Comment: @rakanepicness YES. it matters, because law of the country of the consumer applies in some cases.

Comment: I am in the EU.

Answer (score 6):

You could certainly **allow** twitter to delete the exchange, unless it is part of some record that the law in the relevant country require to be retained, which would be quite unusual. That would depend on the nature of the exchange, and the particular law requiring that records be retained.

However, if the request is to be able to **demand** that Twitter delete the exchange, that would be much harder.  In general a person or business is entitled to retain copies of communications, such as emails, sent to that person or entity.  There is the "right to be forgotten" which applies under EU law, but that would not apply to records which a business needed to retain for its own legitimate purposes, and was not posting publicly, as I understand it. <s>In any case Twitter is not an EU business, so I am not sure if the right would apply at all.</s> (Twitter has an office in Amsterdam, so teh GDPR and other EU law clearly applies to it.)

There might be some other basis on which such a demand could be made, depending on the detailed circumstances and the specific jurisdiction, but I cannot think of one offhand.

Comment: OP didn't ask about the right to *demand*, so I would not answer it.  If it was the question, OP should ask it directly.

Comment: @Harper When the OP wrote "now, I would like them to delete it" I strongly suspect that OP wants to ask if not demand that it be deleted, not just allow it, and phrased the question poorly.

Comment: If the OP is an EU resident, then the rights conferred in the GDPR apply, even though Twitter is not an EU company - that said, its trivially easy enough to come to the conclusion that Twitter may have legitimate grounds that override various rights in the GDPR - for example, the email exchange may be required in any potential legal action taken against Twitter in the future, so can be retained unilaterally for a reasonable period of time.

Comment: @Moo The GDPR says that it applies to any dealings by a non-EU company with an EU resident. I am not convinved that will be enforceable in practice for truly-non-EU firms. There is a recent SE question asking for any reproted cases where the GDPR has been enforced on a non-EU partry. Last I checked no one had listed such a case.

Comment: @DavidSiegel the GDPR is relatively new, so of course enforcement actions will be few and far between thus far - but whether its enforceable or not is separate to whether it legally obliges a US company to do something.  And right now it legally obliges a US company to follow the GDPR.

Comment: @Moo What authority does the EU or any EU law have to impose any duty on a non-EU  entity thsaty is not doing business in the EU? If an EU resident seeks out a non-EU firm, contacting it by mail or over the net, when that firm does not in any meaningful sense do buisness in the EU, why should such a business pay any attention to the EU law at all, unless its local law requires it to follow the EU law? I am far from the fist to raise this point, and i have not seen any convincing answer.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Im not getting into that discussion because its simply ridiculous - every country imposes its laws extraterritorially (the US controls who Airbus sells to, confiscates money sent between two EU residents because the goods involved were Cuban cigars etc etc etc) and has done for decades - the GDPR is no different, and there are plenty of ways to punish Twitter for not complying.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Just, all social media have considerable EU contacts, and twitter is among those. If they don't want to have to abide by EU law, they have to geoblock all of the EU. Which is 446 million people. 110 million **more** than in the US. The EU's 2018 GDP was 18.8 trillion USD, the USA's 2018 GDP 20.54. In effect, to bypass EU laws, you'd loose out on 50% of the western market.

Comment: @Trish  That is quite true. No doubt doing that much business in the EU would provide all the enforcement leverage needed. Which says nothing about whether the "right to be forgotten" would apply in such a case, of course.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Comments to improve your answer are not a place for rhetorical discussions about long-arm statutes. If you're answering questions in a law stack, you reasonably ought to know it's more complicated than that.

Comment: @Harper The issue of the applicability of the GDPR and similar laws is relevant to the question, and so perfectly proper for these comments. That said, it is complex enough to deserve a separate question.

Comment: The question is can OP *allow* them to.  GDPR is not relevant to that. Why don't you just change the question to say "can I FORCE them" since you want to answer  that question so bad? LOL

Comment: @Harper As I said above, I answered as I did because I think the OP implied that question. I won't edit the question because I cannot be sure of the OP's intent. I could wish the OP returned and clarified the intent.

Comment: @Trish if Twitter wants to escape the GDPR it also has to close its office in Amsterdam.

Comment: @Moo, David: Twitter has offices in Amsterdam, so the GDPR unambiguously applies to Twitter.  Twitter is not "a non-EU entity."

Comment: @phoog Thank you, that does make the GDPR applicability issue clear.

Comment: So what should I do? Thanks.